# Visual Studio 2013 can't remove assembly reference

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, dependency-management, projects-and-solutions

I got a new machine and upgraded from VS2012 to VS2013. Now i'm trying to compile a Project with DevExpress. Unfortunately the Compiler cant find the references and i'm not able to remove them from the Project Explorer. I installed the same DevExpress package.

[image: no Options to remove assembly from list]

Comment: Use Tools + Import/Export Settings + Reset all settings to restore context menus to their factory default.  Do note that you can't just arbitrarily remove such an assembly reference, your project is very unlikely to compile.  Re-installing libraries you depend on is required when you migrate to another machine.

Comment: Have you tried simply re-adding these references? They should fix themselves that way.

Comment: Had same problem, Later I found that reference dll are deleted and has that yellow mark over the reference. Then I restored the deleted dll properly in the folder. Adding and Readding Dlls helps, thanks for your comment @jessehouwing

Answer (score 1):

May be you could download that package and install(force installation) them and try to remove them after. Sometime it could help !